# replace 0's with 1's and vice versa for a diagonal matrix in R

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me how to replace 0's with 1's and *vice versa* for a diagonal matrix in R.

Comment: I guess you're using the R programming language?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)

Comment: @shookster yes i'm using R programming

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your matrix is mat and you want to flip all 1s as 0s...

```
mat <- 1-mat
```

Comment: +1 Ah. That makes sense... I probably could have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about R but it seems like you can address a matrix like this:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Array-indexing

I would suspect you could solve your problem using a for loop:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Repetitive-execution

Answer (score 0):

Since matrices are stored in mode of numeric, type of integer/double, and storage mode integer/double (assuming that matrix holds numerical values) you can use simple square bracket indexing to address specific values in them, e.g.

```
# create dummy data
> m <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5)
> mode(m)    # check mode
[1] "numeric"
> typeof(m)  # check type
[1] "double"
> storage.mode(m)
[1] "double"
```

Now, in order to create diagonal matrix, you can use `lower.tri` and `upper.tri` functions, which return logical values for matrix elements beneath and above the main diagonal, respectively.

You can use `lower.tri` and `upper.tri` functions to set off-diagonal elements to 0.

```
> m[lower.tri(m)] <- 0
> m[upper.tri(m)] <- 0
> m
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.3356640  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000 -0.2940369  0.0000000  0.000000 0.0000000
[3,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.4490546  0.000000 0.0000000
[4,] 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -1.093924 0.0000000
[5,] 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000 0.3199157
```

You can, of course, set any constant to lower/upper diagonal elements, be it numerical, character, logical, NA, etc...

Once you have set zeros as an off-diagonal elements, you can simply use square-bracket indexing. A little diversion: bare in mind that mathematically, vectors are special cases of matrices (and *vice versa*), but the same doesn't stand for *R*:

```
> is.vector(m)
[1] FALSE
> is.matrix(1:10)
[1] FALSE
```

But, finally, you **can** do:

```
> m[m == 0] <- 1
```

This will insert 1 in matrix wherever zeros occur. You can use `diag` function to access/change the diagonal elements, for example:

```
> m[m == 1] <- 0
> diag(m) <- rep(pi, 5)
```

will change your diagonal matrix to scalar one.

After this boring post of mine, let us all hope that it helped someone, somehow...

Cheers!

Comment: And to confuse you a bit more, try `m[lower.tri(m)] <- 1:10` and see what happens. =)